# Message: Undefined property: News::$news_model in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am learning Codeigniter from Codeigniter mannual step by step. Therefore i used as it is code from the manual.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

**The Controller class is :**

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller{

    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('news/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
?>
```

**The Model Class is:**

```
    class News_model extends CI_Model{

    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get('news');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news',array('slug'=>$slug));
        return $query->row_array();

    }
?>
```

[image: Screenshot of Filestructure]

Please help me to fix this error. I've Tried every possible solution on internet but couldn't find any mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter uses `__construct` with two `_`.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('news_model');
}
```

The above code should work.

As a side note, you can call your models like this:

```
$this->load->model('news_model', 'news');
```

and then you can call it like this:

```
$this->news->get_news();
```

But your method works fine, just makes it a bit easier.

Comment: It is working fine now. Thanks. Where should i put templates/header.php ?

Comment: In your views folder. Create a new folder called `templates` and put `header.php` in there. @Abhimanu

Comment: can you give me your email or social id so that i can contact you for any further help?